# How to use HTML5 <meter> within an email body in .NET?

Tags: .net, html, email, html-email, mailmessage

I am aware that not all email clients support HTML5 elements, but is there a work around for using a  tag. I have an inline HTML string which I pass into the email body and I am setting the MailMessage.IsBodyHtml Property to true. 
As of right now, when I receive the email in i.e. gmail the browser is rendering an empty u tag  where the meter tag should be.

Comment: Well if you put `<meter>` in the body and the rest of the HTML is working...I'd say the email client doesn't know how to handle `<meter>` and you'll have to use something else.

Comment: This link might help: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: This is true mason. Outlook does the same, that's why I was wondering if a "work around" exist. When will these email clients catch up and handle HTML5